# While calling Web Service using jquery with a SOAP getting 400 bad request error

Tags: jquery, web-services, soap

This is my client side code.While calling this function i'm getting 400 bad request error.Can anyone help me.

```
var req_params="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
              req_params = req_params + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
              req_params = req_params + "<soap:Header>";
             req_params = req_params + "<UserDetails>";
             req_params = req_params + "<Lastname>Abubakar</Lastname>";
             req_params = req_params + "<Othernames>Uju, Ayo</Othernames>";
             req_params = req_params + "<Email>me@me.com</Email>";
              req_params = req_params + "<Phone>08032458829</Phone>";
             req_params = req_params + "</UserDetails>";
             req_params = req_params + "</soap:Body>";
             req_params = req_params + "</soap:Envelope>";
             console.log(req_params);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://testservices.interswitchng.com/quicktellerservice/quickteller.svc/CreateUser",
    data: req_params, 
    processData:false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },        
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    } 
});
```

Comment: can you show your `req_params`?

Comment: @benedict_w i added req_params

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this is you can't make a cross domain call without modifying  the web service you’re working with. You can find more about this if you google "jquery cross domain ajax".

Here you can read more about this: http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

And here you will find an example of cross domain XML call: http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-xml-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/